# Prove this claim without using Great Picard's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $B'(0,r)$ (punctured disc of radius $r$ with center $0$) with an essencial singularity in $0$. Prove that, given $k\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$, there are infinite $z\in B'(0,r)$ that verify $|f(z)|=k.$

I'm trying to prove this claim without using [Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem). I've tried to apply [Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), but I haven't really gone anywhere with it. ¿Is there any way to prove this without using Picard's theorem(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that for some $k > 0$ there are only finitely many $z$ with $|f(z)| = k$. By making the radius $r$ smaller you can assume that $|f(z)| \ne k$ for all $z \in B'(0, r)$.  Since $|f|$ is continuous it follows that

- either $|f(z)| < k$ for all $z \in B'(0, r)$,
- or $|f(z)| > k$ for all $z \in B'(0, r)$.

Now apply Casorati-Weierstrass (or Riemann's theorem on removable singularities) to $f$ or to $1/f$.

Comment: Just to be sure: by aplying Casorati-Weierstrass, I'd find that $f(B'(0,r))$ (for the smaller radius $r$) is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, arriving at a contradiction, right?

Comment: You find that the image is *not dense* and that is a contradiction to having an essential singularity. [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) is also sufficient here because $f$ (or $1/f$) is bounded. (Casorati-Weierstrass is a consequence of that theorem.)